# applescript - copy paste sender's email address to numbers

Tags: email, applescript, applescript-numbers

is it possible that when a new email message is received to run applescript to copy sender’s email address to clipboard and paste it to next empty cell in column e in numbers, I've been trying with this, but it doesn't select the first message

thanks in advance :)

```js
property workFlowPath : quoted form of ("/Users/pl 1/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/accepted.workflow") --CHANGE THIS TO YOUR FULL WORKFLOW FILE PATH example  "/Users/pl 1/Library/Application Scripts/com.apple.mail/accepted.workflow"


using terms from application "Mail"
 on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule
  repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
   (*Get the email Subject *)
   
   set input_Argument to subject of eachMessage
   (*Run subroutine for workflow *)
   my runAutomator(input_Argument)
  end repeat
 end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from

(*Workflow  Subroutine *)
on runAutomator(input_Argument)
 
 (*Path to workflow *)
 
 
 (*Setup and Run the unix command *)
 set command to "/usr/bin/automator   -i " & quoted form of input_Argument & space & workFlowPath
 do shell script command
end runAutomator
```

```html
on run {input, parameters}
 
 tell application "Numbers"
  tell application "Finder"
   set theFile to POSIX file “/Users/pl 1/Google Drive/Publication Submission Tracker2.numbers"
   open theFile
  end tell
  
 end tell
 
 return input
end run



________pause for 5 seconds______



tell application "Mail"
 reopen
 activate
 set theSenderList to {}
 set theMessages to the first message of message viewer 0
 repeat with aMessage in theMessages
  set oneAddress to extract address from sender of aMessage
  set end of theSenderList to oneAddress
 end repeat
 set the clipboard to (theSenderList as string)
end tell
return
end run

________pause for 5 seconds______



tell application "Numbers"
 reopen
 activate
 tell application "System Events" to tell process "Numbers"
  set currentCell to "e2"
  keystroke "v" using {command down}
 end tell
end tell

end run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is best not to use UI scripting here. You want to set this up as a trigger in mail.app. Your script can pull the sender email address and then programmatically add it to the first empty cell in a row. Here's a script to get you started:

```
using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages theMessages for rule theRule

        tell application id "com.apple.iWork.Numbers"
            activate
            -- can also tell Numbers to open a specific document
        end tell

        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with eachMessage in theMessages
                set fromAddress to extract address from reply to of eachMessage

                tell application id "com.apple.iWork.Numbers"
                    tell document 1
                        tell the active sheet
                            tell table 1
                                tell column "E" -- change to preferred column
                                    -- find the last empty row in this column
                                    set r to (address of row of first cell whose value is missing value)
                                    set value of cell r to fromAddress
                                    set r to r + 1
                                end tell
                            end tell
                        end tell
                    end tell
                end tell

            end repeat
        end tell
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

Edit: I edited the script to check for the next cell with a  'missing value' (instead of the cell value > 0) so that it can handle numbers and dates, such as:
set value of cell r to date "12/5/15"

Comment: Thank you, it works well, I'm new to applescript so it is still bit confusing :)

Comment: Would it be possible  to do the same with dates ?  been trying and can't get it work with dates but it works perfectly with words ?                                         set r to r + 1
set value of cell r to date string of (current date)

Comment: Yes, I changed the approach of the line that finds the next empty cell to properly handle number values in cells as well, by making it look for the first cell whose value is missing value